# Session cookies and http headers

Tags: python, http, session, request

I'm did a login system to experiment a login script in python, the login system has a form token which i extract from the page with regex (so i can post it along with username/password after), that's what i'm trying to avoid. So i did this example code to show you, and maybe you can anser me. Is there anyway besides this one to extract the `session` vars.

My php code:

```
<?php
session_start();
$_SESION['token'] = md5(time());
?>
<input type="hidden" name="token" value="<?= $_SESION['token']; ?>">
```

My 'login script' (just the part relevant about the token extracion):

```
import requests
import re

s = requests.Session()
headers = {
    "User-agent" : 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.7; rv:7.0.1) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/7.0.1',
    "Referer": 'https://www.google.com'
}
req = s.get('http://migueldvl.com/heya/login/tests.php', headers=headers)
token = re.compile('<input type="hidden" name="token" value="(.*?)">').search(req.text).group(1)
print('page: ', req.text)
print('token: ', token)

print('\nheaders we sent: ', req.request.headers)
print('\nheaders server sent back: ', req.headers) # (nothing about the token session here)
```

You guys are welcome to test the code (python3) in this [url](http://migueldvl.com/heya/login/tests.php), it's not blank if you view source

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't retrieve session variables defined in PHP this way:

> A session is a way to store information (in variables) to be used
>   across multiple pages.
>
> Unlike a cookie, the information is not stored on the users computer.

*Source: http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_sessions.asp*

**Regex alternative**

Alternatively to using regex, you could use [BeautifulSoup](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/) ([docs](http://beautiful-soup-4.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#)) to extract the token value:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

r = s.get('http://migueldvl.com/heya/login/tests.php', headers=headers)
r.raise_for_status()

soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'lxml')

# Simple reference
token = soup.html.body.input['value']

# With more attributes specified
token = soup.html.body.find('input', attrs={'name':'token', 'type':'hidden'})['value']
```

Comment: Thank you Kristof. Got it. But anwser me this: if it's not stored in my computer how come if i delete my cookies/history from the browser my sessions are destroyed as well?